# cannot resolve method setBuiltInZoomControls & getController

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using a `MapsActivity` which is giving me errors showing `cannot resolve method 'setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)`'

and `cannot resolve method 'getController()'`

and `cannot resolve method 'setUseDataConnection(boolean)'`

This is my MapsActivity.java

```
    package com.example.app6;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;

    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            MapView mapView = new MapView(this, 256);
            mapView.setClickable(true);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            setContentView(mapView);
            mapView.getController().setZoom(14);    
            mapView.getController().setCenter(new Barcode.GeoPoint(52.221,6.893));
mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);

        }
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            // Add a marker in Jaipur and move the camera
            LatLng jpr = new LatLng(26.8473727, 75.8104005);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(jpr).title("Marker in Jaipur"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(jpr));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;`

But to use `setBuiltInZoomControls()` on a mapView you should use `com.google.android.maps.MapView`.

So the problem is you are trying to new and old **`Google Maps API`**

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/mapview"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:apiKey="your key">
```

But my suggestion is ; use latest version of [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)

Comment: I can't use this one "import com.google.android.maps.MapView;" showing cannot resolve symbol Mapview, in that directory or package.